# What is the Discrete Fourier Transform of a periodic sequence?

Tags: fourier-analysis, modular-arithmetic, fourier-transform, online-resources, fast-fourier-transform

Shor's algorithm utilises the properties of quantum computers to find $r$ in,
$$
a^r = 1 \mod n
$$
wherein $r$ is even and $a^{r/2} + 1\neq 0$. However I haven't been able to find any resources in how this relates to the Discrete Fourier Transform? As in how is the DFT of a sequence taken?